# Responsive design using 3 columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a page with 3 columns, the left and right columns must have a fixed width (for example 100px) and height must fixed too (for 100% of screen) and you can't scroll them. The center column must occupy all the remaining space and you can scroll this.

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2L9686o0/2/
- Red div should occupy the entire area and not as in my example.

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: why didn't you use `table` and `td` tages instead of `div`?

Comment: @mahmoudadam can you show me sites that uses such page structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/2L9686o0/3/

Basically you need to ensure your body and html elements have 100% height, and then give your centre div a min-height of 100% too.

It doesn't need a fixed position or anything like that, just these styles:

```
.main-center{
    background-color:red; 
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 240px;
    min-height: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I also put `top: 0` on your left and right divs to ensure they right at the top, else the right-hand one gets pushed down by the content of the centre.

**Edit:** To force long un-broken text to wrap, add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `.main-center` class. I've updated the example above, and the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2L9686o0/5/

Comment: I add some text, and Text came out of screen [https://jsfiddle.net/2L9686o0/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/2L9686o0/4/)